# If autocomplete is at the bottom of the page, autocomplete options float above text area

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

We are using this autocomplete plugin: [jQuery AutoComplete](http://fromvega.com/wordpress/2007/05/05/auto-complete-field-with-jquery-json-php/)

However, there's a problem when the input field is at the bottom of the page. The auto complete list (the one that appears once you start typing) shifts its position so that instead of dropping down the text box, it floats above the text box instead. It's okay if there's a lot of items in the list. However, if the options are few and the height isn't enough, there's a huge gap between the input box and the autocomplete box.

To make it clearer here's the image:

[image: Auto Complete Box Problem]

Does anybody know how to modify the code so that this doesn't happen? Or so that the AutoComplete always remain at the bottom of the input box no matter what?

I think this is the part of the jQuery that does it:

```
// reposition the results div accordingly to the search field

function repositionResultsDiv()
{
    // get the field position
    var sf_pos    = acSearchField.offset();
    var sf_top    = sf_pos.top;
    var sf_left   = sf_pos.left;

    // get the field size
    var sf_height = acSearchField.height();
//  var sf_width  = acSearchField.width();
    var sf_width  = 285;

    // apply the css styles - optimized for Firefox
    acResultsDiv.css("position","absolute");
    acResultsDiv.css("zIndex", 1000);
    acResultsDiv.css("left", sf_left - 2);
    acResultsDiv.css("top", sf_top + sf_height + 5);
    acResultsDiv.css("width", sf_width - 2);
}
```

Apparently, the top offset value should be bigger (so that it is pushed further down) but it doesn't seem to calculate it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out the problem. Apparently, on that particular page, some content is being generated after the page loads so the offset value doesn't take into account the height of that additional content.

What I temporarily did as a solution was to use a different ID for that page and put a condition on the jQuery to add a specific height if that ID is detected. I think I need to use some live method or maybe to load that piece of content first before the autosuggest script is loaded but for now this temporary fix will do.

Answer (score 0):

There is a "position" attribute you can control. You can do complex things with it, or simple things. http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete#option-position

Note that what jQuery does by default is try to find a position that doesn't collide. If you change that, make sure you don't change it for the worse.